# Custom Preference Category won't show Text title

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to get my Preference category header to be consistent with the theme of my app, so after searching around both on SO and some blogs I follow..I found the best(and easiest) way was just to create a custom Preference Category class that overrides onCreateView() or onBindView() and programmatically set the color of the category TextView and it's background. Sounds easy enough.

My only two caveats is that I'm using a SherlockPreferenceActivity, and therefore I'm not able to simply apply a custom theme to my Activity since I have to use a Sherlock theme or a derivative. Also, my other thing(and I think this may be the cause) is that I'm trying to set the TextView's background to a Shape Drawable, which is a gradient with a stroke in xml. The background of the preference category changes just fine, but I don't see any TextView at all, which leads to me to think that maybe the background is being drawn on top of it's textView? I'm not sure

Here's the code for my CustomPreferenceCategory class. As you can see I tried it both using onBindView() and onCreateView().

```
public class CustomPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {



public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
    super(context);



}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);



}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context);



}


 @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.header_non_rounded);
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    }



//@Override
/*protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    // And it's just a TextView!
    TextView categoryTitle = (TextView) super.onCreateView(parent);
    categoryTitle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.header_non_rounded);
    categoryTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



    return categoryTitle;
}*/
```

}

Here's how I'm setting it via my preferences.xml file

```
<com.brightr.weathermate.views.CustomPreferenceCategory android:title="Weather"      >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="degreesC"
        android:summary="Display the weather degrees in Celsius units"
        android:title="Show Celsius" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="degreesF"
        android:summary="Display the weather in Farenheit units"
        android:title="Show Farenheit" />

    <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/textColors"
        android:entryValues="@array/textColor_values"
        android:summary="Change the color of the temerature text"
        android:title="Temperature Text Color" />
</com.brightr.weathermate.views.CustomPreferenceCategory>
```

Any thoughts as to why only the background is being changed but the TextView is not visible? Also, even when I use setBackgroundResource() instead of setBackgroundDrawable(), it still doesn't set the text. Any help would be greatly appreciate guys.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Silly me, I forgot to pass in the other two params in each of the constructors. I feel like kicking myself.

```
public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
super(context);



}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);



}

public CustomPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
    int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);



}
```